# cross entropy loss with weight manual calculation

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

Hi just playing around with code, I got the unexpected result of cross entropy loss weight implementation.

```
pred=torch.tensor([[8,5,3,2,6,1,6,8,4],[2,5,1,3,4,6,2,2,6],[1,1,5,8,9,2,5,2,8],[2,2,6,4,1,1,7,8,3],[2,2,2,7,1,7,3,4,9]]).float()
label=torch.tensor([[3],[7],[8],[2],[5]],dtype=torch.int64)
weights=torch.tensor([1,1,1,10,1,6,1,1,1],dtype=torch.float32)
```

with this kind of sample variables, pytorch's cross entropy loss gives out 4.7894

```
loss = F.cross_entropy(pred, label, weight=weights,reduction='mean')
> 4.7894
```

I manually implemented the cross entropy loss code as below

```
one_hot = torch.zeros_like(pred).scatter(1, label.view(-1, 1), 1)
log_prb = F.log_softmax(pred, dim=1)
loss = -(one_hot * log_prb).sum(dim=1).mean()
```

this kind of implementation gives same result with pytorch's cross entropy function if given without weight value. However with weight value

```
one_hot = torch.zeros_like(pred).scatter(1, label.view(-1, 1), 1)
log_prb = F.log_softmax(pred, dim=1)
loss = -(one_hot * log_prb)*weights.sum(dim=1).sum()/weights.sum()
> 3.9564
```

it gives out different loss value with pytorch module(4.7894).
I can roughly estimate that my understanding of loss's weight have some problem here, but I can't find out the exact reason for this kind of discrepancy.
Can anybody help me handling this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. It was quite simple...
I shouldn't have divided with the whole sum of weights.
Instead with dividing with `wt.sum()` (`wt=one_hot*weight`) got me *4.7894*.

```
>>> wt = one_hot*weights
>>> loss = -(one_hot * log_prb * weights).sum(dim=1).sum() / wt.sum()
4.7894
```

The denominator was only with 'related' weight value, not whole.